# Extract ZIP's filename where the root is a directory

Tags: php, zip

Hello I am looking for a way to extract the ZIP's filenames and create a tree in my website of the zip's contents. I don't want to extract the file itself I just want to loop through the zip file and print out it's contents.

This includes, sub-folders etc.
I found a good answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2600105/need-php-script-to-decompress-and-loop-through-zipped-file) with the following code as a solution:

```
$zip = new ZipArchive; 
if ($zip->open('source.zip') === TRUE) 
{ 
     for($i = 0; $i < $zip->numFiles; $i++) 
     {   
        $fp = $zip->getStream($zip->getNameIndex($i));
        if(!$fp) exit("failed\n");
        while (!feof($fp)) {
            $contents = fread($fp, 8192);
            // do some stuff
        }
        fclose($fp);
     }
} 
else 
{ 
     echo 'Error reading zip-archive!'; 
}
```

but this won't work for the sub-directories.

But another gap that I found is the following, if the whole zip archive has as a root only a directory, and within this directory are all the others files then the method $zip->numFiles will return 0 , and therefore the loop (in the example above) will not run !

So in general I think this won't work always. One solution that I think is to do recursion but this will be hard to implement, so I am looking for alternatives.