# How to unzip a zip file that has another zip file inside using PHP

Tags: php, zip, unzip

I have a file **xyz.zip** and in this file there are two more files **test.xml** and another **abc.zip** file that contains **test2.xml**. When i use this code it only extract **xyz.zip** file. But i also need to extract **abc.zip**.

xyz.zip
 - test.xml
 - abc.zip
   - test2.xml

```
<?php
$filename = "xzy.zip";
$zip = new ZipArchive;
if ($zip->open($filename) === TRUE) {
        $zip->extractTo('./');
        $zip->close();
        echo 'Success!';
}
else {
        echo 'Error!';
}
?>
```

Can somebody please tell me how can i extract everything in zip files? Even abc.zip. So that the output will be in a folder (test.xml and test2.xml).

Thanks

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Need PHP script to decompress and loop through zipped file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2600105/need-php-script-to-decompress-and-loop-through-zipped-file)

Answer (score 0):

this might help you.

This function will flatten a zip file using the ZipArchive class.

It will extract all the files in the zip and store them in a single destination directory.  That is, no sub-directories will be created.

```
<?php
// dest shouldn't have a trailing slash
function zip_flatten ( $zipfile, $dest='.' )
{
    $zip = new ZipArchive;
    if ( $zip->open( $zipfile ) )
    {
        for ( $i=0; $i < $zip->numFiles; $i++ )
        {
            $entry = $zip->getNameIndex($i);
            if ( substr( $entry, -1 ) == '/' ) continue; // skip directories

            $fp = $zip->getStream( $entry );
            $ofp = fopen( $dest.'/'.basename($entry), 'w' );

            if ( ! $fp )
                throw new Exception('Unable to extract the file.');

            while ( ! feof( $fp ) )
                fwrite( $ofp, fread($fp, 8192) );

            fclose($fp);
            fclose($ofp);
        }

                $zip->close();
    }
    else
        return false;

    return $zip;
}

/*
How to use:

zip_flatten( 'test.zip', 'my/path' );
*/
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use a recursive function that check all the extracted files and if it finds out one of them is a zip, then call itself again.

```
function scanDir($path) {
    $files = scandir($path);
    foreach($files as $file) {
        if (substr($file, -4)=='.zip')
            unzipRecursive($path, $file);
        elseif (isdir($path.'/'.$file))
            scanDir($path.'/'.$file);
    }
}

function unzipRecursive($absolutePath, $filename) {
    $zip = new ZipArchive;
    $newfolder = $absolutePath.'/'.substr($file, 0, -4);
    if ($zip->open($filename) === TRUE) {
        $zip->extractTo($newfolder);
        $zip->close();
        //Scan the directory
        scanDir($newfolder)
    } else {
        echo 'Error unzipping '.$absolutePath.'/'.$filename;
    }
}
```

I didn't try the code but it's only to debug a little I guess